# jedit navigating file system with keys when opening a file

Tags: jedit

How to make jedit navigating file system with left, down keys. So when in the ctrl-o form, if I press left key after the cursor is at the first character of file name, it should jump up the file browser tree and every left key press would move up higher in directory. It used to work out of the box with 5-6 old jedit, but these newer versions, I can't get it to work.
This alone made me love jedit for so many years.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative usage is to type `..` into the filename label then <kbd>enter</kbd> ( or `../..` to go up two levels ).  To go down into a directory or open a file name, type the few characters of the file or directory then hit <kbd>tab</kbd> to autocomplete the name of the node then <kbd>enter</kbd>.  Once you autocomplete the name you can use the up and down arrows to select in the current directory hierarchy.

Not a direct answer, but I find this to be a rather quick mode.

Alternatively, you can switch focus to the file hierarchy pane with <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> , <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> and then use the arrow keys.  Not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for, because I don't use this navigation mode.

I prefer my previous answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Since I posted this question, I have tried several other editors and none of them works to my liking. So, I downloaded jedit 4.1 which I"m so used to. It'll do OK for me.